# Not a valid namespace identifier

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to follow a tutorial [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/11/01/retrieving-storing-and-displaying-data.aspx?m=1), called Retrieving, Storing and Displaying Data in Windows Phone Apps

First I have to create design time data in Blend, which worked out.
The items have a green or red border, depending on a data value. I copy pasted the code needed to convert a certain number in a color.

In xaml I need to copy this line:

```
<local:SeverityColorConverter x:Key="SeverityColorConverter" DefaultAndLowPriorityColor="Green" HighPriorityColor="Red"/>
```

However, the local keyword confuses me.

Long story short: I copied the overal xaml code that is provided to see how it should work out,
and I got all kinds of namespace errors: for example

```
The URI "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;     assembly=Microsoft.Phone" is not a valid namespace identifier.
```

As I am new to programming for windows phone, I am totally confused. Excuse me for the the confusing way of asking for help on this one, as I am totally mixed up.

Any help would be appreciated! I provide the XAML code below, the tutorial itself can be found via the link above.

```
Here's the complete XAML mark up for this page:
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
  xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
    assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc=
    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
  x:Class="Defects.AddDefectPage"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefectTypesItemTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
      <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton 
        IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/feature.camera.png"
        Text="photo" />
      <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton 
        IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/save.png"
        Text="save" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
  </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent"
      d:DataContext=
        "{Binding Source={StaticResource AddDefectDataSource}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
          Margin="12,17,0,28">
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
        Text="DEFECTS" />
      <TextBlock Text="new defect"
        Margin="9,-7,0,0"
        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Margin="12,-12,12,0">

      <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Width="200"
        Height="200">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black"
          BorderThickness="1"
          Background=
            "{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}"
          Opacity="0.1" />

        <Image Source="{Binding NewDefect.Photo}" />

      </Grid>
      <TextBlock Text="Title"
        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
      <TextBox Height="72"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Text="{Binding NewDefect.Title, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      <toolkit:ListPicker Header="Defect Type"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefectTypesItemTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DefectTypes}"
        FullModeItemTemplate=
          "{StaticResource DefectTypesItemTemplate}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a problem with correctly parsing the namespace. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284450/reference-name-space-in-another-project-in-wpf-xaml-file) could help you.

Projected on your example instead of referencing the namespace like so

```
clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;     assembly=Microsoft.Phone
```

you should instead remove the leading whitespaces before *assembly*

```
clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone
```